# Some properties of the matrix $A^\top A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ It is clear that $A^tA$ is a symmetric and hance diagonalizable matrix. However, I don't know how to prove that

> 1. the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ are non-negative and if $A$ is not the null matrix at least one eigenvalue is strictly positive;
> 2. if we define the bilinear form $g: \mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(v,w)= (v^\top A^\top )(Aw)$, then it is a
>      positive defined scalar product iff $\text{rank}(A)=n$.

Can you show me how to prove (1) and (2)?

Comment: Use `^\top` for transposes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using the standard inner product $\langle v,w\rangle:=v^tw$, we can see the adjointness property of the transpose:
   $$\langle v,Aw\rangle=\langle A^tv,w\rangle$$
   for all $v,w$.

Now, suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, i.e. $A^tAv=\lambda v$ for a nonzero vector $v$. Then
$$\lambda\cdot\|v\|^2=\langle\lambda v,v\rangle=\langle A^tAv,v\rangle=\langle Av,Av\rangle=\|Av\|^2$$
where $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=x^tx$ is the (square of the) standard norm.

So that, $\lambda=\displaystyle\frac{\|Av\|^2}{\|v\|^2}\ge 0$.

This being an equality means $Av=0$ for all corresponding eigenvectors. Since $A^tA$ is diagonalizable, if all its eigenvalues are $0$, then $A^tA=0$ follows, so every vector is an eigenvector of it, hence $Av=0$ by above.

2. **Hint:** What happens to $g$ if $\ker A$ contains a nonzero $w$?